# What is the difference betweeen "MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON" and "application/json"

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am new to Jersey.
For return type, I would like to know:

What is the difference between `application/json` and `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`?

What is the right term to put in `@Produces()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are mean the same thing. The different is that the `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` is a constant value.

I think better is to put constant value wherever possible because if you put a string value you can make typo. In constant value you have certainty that the value under this constant is correct.

Other thing if you have to put the same string value in some different places and you make typo you have to check each place where you put this string value. In constant value you have to make a change only in one place.

---

From [`MediaType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_JSON) javadoc:

> APPLICATION_JSON
>
> public static final java.lang.String APPLICATION_JSON
>   "application/json"

Comment: You can event add a @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8") to mark it UTF-8 encoding. So it's realy only a String, to prevent typo, or faster changes if you implement other media types